# Query and return all foreign key values as array in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The goal is to store and query JSON array values in MySQL v5.7.

Given two tables country(id,fullName) and country_synonyms(country_id,synonyms), with one to many relationship through foreign key country id:

```
CREATE TABLE country(id INT, fullName VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE country_synonyms(country_id INT,synonyms VARCHAR(255));
ALTER TABLE country ADD CONSTRAINT c_pk PRIMARY KEY(id);
ALTER TABLE country_synonyms ADD CONSTRAINT cs_pk PRIMARY KEY(country_id,synonyms);
ALTER TABLE country_synonyms ADD CONSTRAINT c_fk FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO country(id,fullName) VALUES (1,'Afghanistan');
INSERT INTO country_synonyms(country_id,synonyms) VALUES (1,'afghanistan'),(1,'afg'),(1,'islamic republic of afghanistan');
```

Listing the synonyms as array works with:

```
SELECT
  T1.id,
  T1.fullName,
  cast(concat('[', group_concat(json_quote(T2.synonyms) ORDER BY synonyms SEPARATOR ','), ']') as json) AS synonyms
FROM country T1
LEFT JOIN country_synonyms T2
ON T1.id = T2.country_id
WHERE T1.id=1
GROUP BY country_id;

+----+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | fullName    | synonyms                                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Afghanistan | ["afg", "afghanistan", "islamic republic of afghanistan"] |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Search by synonyms only return the queried value as in

```
SELECT
  T1.id,
  T1.fullName,
  cast(concat('[', group_concat(json_quote(T2.synonyms) ORDER BY synonyms SEPARATOR ','), ']') as json) AS synonyms
FROM country T1
LEFT JOIN country_synonyms T2
ON T1.id = T2.country_id
WHERE T2.synonyms='afg'
GROUP BY country_id;`

+----+-------------+----------+
| id | fullName    | synonyms |
+----+-------------+----------+
|  1 | Afghanistan | ["afg"]  |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

How to do "list all country synonyms that has synonyms 'afg'" ?

EDIT: 
I find this query returns the array i want:

```
SELECT
  T1.id,
  T1.fullName,
  cast(concat('[', group_concat(json_quote(T2.synonyms) ORDER BY synonyms SEPARATOR ','), ']') as json) AS synonyms
FROM country T1
LEFT JOIN country_synonyms T2
ON T1.id = T2.country_id
WHERE T1.id in (select country_id from country_synonyms where synonyms='afg')
GROUP BY country_id;
```

But it's doing an extra scan on the country_synonyms table, could there be a better solution in terms of performance?

Comment: Use [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) rather than constructing the JSON array with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE x IN (SELECT ...)` can almost always be turned into a `JOIN`, and this usually has better performance.

And to collect values from selected rows into a JSON array, use [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) rather than `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.fullName, JSON_ARRAYAGG(t2.synonyms) AS synonyms
FROM country AS t1
JOIN country_synonyms AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.country_id
JOIN country_synonyms AS t2 ON t1.id = t3.country_id
WHERE t3.synonyms = 'afg'
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Also, you don't need to use `LEFT JOIN` since the conditions imply that there will always be at least one match in `country_synonyms`.